# how to define a df in a sublist using imap

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of list, and each sublist also have multiple df. Now I would like to know the number of cols in each df in each sublist using `imap`. How can I get point to the df correctly.

**Sample list can be built using**:

```
lst1<-list(`101-01-101` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-01-101"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1953-07-07"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-01-101"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2016-03-14"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), `101-02-102` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-02-102"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1963-07-02"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-02-102"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2017-04-04"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), `101-03-103` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-03-103"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1940-09-11"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Male")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-03-103"), DSDT = c("DS Date", NA), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
"UN-UNK-2015")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), `101-04-104` = list(Demographics = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("Subject ID", "101-04-104"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", 
    "1955-12-31"), SEX = c("Gender", "Male")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("Subject ID", "101-04-104"), DSDT = c("DS Date", 
    "2016-05-02"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), `104-05-201` = list(
    Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
    "104-05-201"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1950-12-04"), SEX = c("Gender", 
    "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
    "104-05-201"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2018-07-06"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))))
```

I tried to use two imap to get to that level, but lost the direction at the end. Could someone help me on this and tell me how to correctly point the df in sublist.

my codes is sth like this:

```
   imap ( ~ { 
   wb = createWorkbook()
     imap(.x, ~ {     
       addWorksheet(wb, .y)
       writeData(wb, .y, .x)
       setColWidths(wb, .y, cols = 1:ncol(.x), widths = "auto")
      })

saveWorkbook(wb, file.path("C:/Users/",
                sprintf("subject_%s.xlsx", .y)))
                }
  )
```

Update:

if the df in sublist contain sth like this:

[image]

Comment: what is your expected output format?

Comment: I just update my post. I tried to make `cols = 1:ncol(.x)` to work.

Comment: see my edited answer, if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now I am unable to understand your code, but this should be re-written as.  Not sure what you want where I have put a blank line

```
imap ( ~ { 
   wb = createWorkbook()
     imap(.x, function(a, b) {     
       addWorksheet(wb, b)
       writeData(wb, b, a)
       setColWidths(wb, b, cols = 1:ncol(a), widths = "auto")
      })

saveWorkbook(wb, file.path("C:/Users/",
                sprintf("subject_%s.xlsx", _________)))
                }
  )
```

---

Actually you have two problems there -

- invisible function inside `imap_*` require two arguments.
- Now your another problem is to write one lambda function inside another.  That's an issue I have not solved till date.

Your earlier written expression can be correctly written as

```
imap(lst1, function(.x, .y) imap(.x, function(xy, yz) print(ncol(xy))))

[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
$`101-01-101`
$`101-01-101`$Demographics
[1] 3

$`101-01-101`$DiseaseStatus
[1] 3


$`101-02-102`
$`101-02-102`$Demographics
[1] 3

$`101-02-102`$DiseaseStatus
[1] 3


$`101-03-103`
$`101-03-103`$Demographics
[1] 3

$`101-03-103`$DiseaseStatus
[1] 3


$`101-04-104`
$`101-04-104`$Demographics
[1] 3

$`101-04-104`$DiseaseStatus
[1] 3


$`104-05-201`
$`104-05-201`$Demographics
[1] 3

$`104-05-201`$DiseaseStatus
[1] 3
```

---

Alternatively, if you want something else

```
imap_dfr(lst1, ~ .x %>% as.data.frame() %>% ncol())
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  `101-01-101` `101-02-102` `101-03-103` `101-04-104` `104-05-201`
         <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
1            6            6            6            6            6
```

Or this?

```
map_df(lst1, ~map(.x, function(xy) ncol(xy)))
# map_df(lst1, ~map(.x, ncol)) ##alternative
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Demographics DiseaseStatus
         <int>         <int>
1            3             3
2            3             3
3            3             3
4            3             3
5            3             3
```

Comment: `ncol` that I want should be sth you got from 2nd part. How to put this part into my old codes. should I update it to `ncol(.x.y)`?

Comment: see first part of my edited answer, @Stataq

Comment: I know` imap` sort of equal `Map`. If I rewrite it as `Map`, will that help? I am new to both them , so not sure how to move further.

Comment: What is `xy`, `yz` stands for?

Comment: These are arbitrary names of arguments, you may chose yourself.  But remember, you'll use only first one from these (in the instant case).  Actually `imap_*(list, ~{ .x * .y })` is equivalent to `imap_*(list, function(.x, .y) { .x * .y })` or `imap_*(list, function(a, b) { a * b })`

Comment: I think the problem is from my list. some of df in sublist is empty. Is it possible to run ` setColWidths(wb, b, cols = 1:ncol(a), widths = "auto")`  only if a is not empty?

Comment: try using unvectorised `if`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232918/discussion-between-stataq-and-anilgoyal).

Answer (score 3):

You can `map_depth` to great advantage. You just have to assign a value to `.depth` argument so the function will be applied as many levels deep as you specified. In order to have a nicer looking output I just made 2 modifications:

```
library(purrr)

map_depth(lst1, 2, ~ length(.x)) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% bind_cols())

$`101-01-101`
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Demographics DiseaseStatus
         <int>         <int>
1            3             3

$`101-02-102`
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Demographics DiseaseStatus
         <int>         <int>
1            3             3

$`101-03-103`
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Demographics DiseaseStatus
         <int>         <int>
1            3             3

$`101-04-104`
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Demographics DiseaseStatus
         <int>         <int>
1            3             3

$`104-05-201`
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  Demographics DiseaseStatus
         <int>         <int>
1            3             3
```

Or this one. However the output is not quite informative.

```
map_depth(lst1, 2, ~ length(.x)) %>%
  map(~ .x %>% bind_cols()) %>%
  exec(rbind, !!!.)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Demographics DiseaseStatus
*        <int>         <int>
1            3             3
2            3             3
3            3             3
4            3             3
5            3             3
```

Comment: I just update my post. Is it a way to  make this  work for the part `cols = 1:ncol(.x)`. where ncol(.x) is the part that your get from `map_lengh`. but I am not sure how to loop this in

Comment: You would like to know the number of cols in each underlying tibble?

Comment: Yew. as I need that info to make `setColWidths` works.

Comment: I understand. If I'm not mistaken we discussed it last night. Unfortunately I'm not quite familiar with this package you are using.

Comment: It's ok, but I guess these solutions also get your desired results.